# How to run klee with jdk?

Tags: java, klee

I am new to KLEE, I want to run klee tool in java can you please tell me is it possible to run KLEE in java ? it yes, please show me some tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KLEE works on LLVM bitcode, I don't think it's possible to run klee in JAVA. If you are just looking for a symbolic execution tool for JAVA, you can try [JPF](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki).

Comment: It could be possible for java code snippet with the same technique used in https://github.com/floyd-fuh/AFL_GCJ_Fuzzing_Simple. i.e. compile java code with gcj.